# Python как сделать автозагрузку программы при запуске

Tags: python, python-3.x, download

у меня есть такой код:

```
print("123")
```

можно ли сделать чтобы программа автоматический запускалась при старте windows

Comment: при старте чего? ну и да - можно

Comment: @5c0rp windows чтобы программа сама себя добавила в автозагрузку

Comment: Можно через планировщик заданий, или скомпилить в exe и добавить в папку авторуна. P.S. Если Сама себя добавляла то это уже другая история будет

Comment: @Kers мне нужна чтобы моя программа автоматически себя добавила в автозагрузку чтобы пользователю не чего делать не пришлось

Comment: напоминает сказку про кашу из топора - к этому коду надо еще пару строчек с ключами реестра - почитайте про то куда надо записывать и как в реестре, чтобы программа запускалась при загрузку

Comment: @main На само деле покажите хотя бы какие-то основы того что вы пытались сделать, а мы уже дополним и поправим код до рабочего состояния. А то `print("hello world")` это даже не попытка.